# Shape appears to have less vertexes than shape data THREE.JS

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create a smooth "wave" when the mouse moves over isometric logo shape.

I've created in in processing now I'm trying to recreate it in THREE.js

The shape acts strangely - the shape doesn't look as smooth when elevated compared to the processing sketch. If you look at the edges you can see segments that are not supposed to be there. I'm not sure what causes this.

Basically the shape is created through a loops that goes over 2 arrays:

```
for (var i = 0; i < xpos0.length; i++) {

    shape.lineTo(xpos0[i], ypos0[i]);

  }
```

Then it animates through another for loop that checks the distance between verteces[i].x and mouse location intersection with the ground

```
for (let p = 0; p < mesh.geometry.vertices.length; p=p+1) {

    let delta = Math.abs(mesh.geometry.vertices[p].x - intersects[0].point.x);
    mesh.geometry.vertices[p].z = bump2(-2, 2000, -1, 2, delta);

  }
```

z value is calculated through this function:

```
function bump2(a,b,c,d,xval) {
  xval = parseFloat(xval);
  // console.log(typeof xval);
  return Math.exp(a / (-xval * xval / b + c) + d) * -1;
}
```

**https://codepen.io/NotYetDesignLab/pen/JjYaqRJ**

---

**How it looks on THREE.JS**

notice how some segments appear "broken", like it's made of stiff parts instead of the many points that make up the segment in the array and give the illusion of "paper".

[image]

---

**THIS IS HOW IT'S SUPPOSED TO LOOK: (Processing/java)**

This has been done using Processing. Notice how the elevation of the edges is smooth and not broken.

[image]

Comment: This happens because the shape is triangulated in an optimized way. Lifting certain vertices will lift faces in an unexpected way (see https://jsfiddle.net/1boqLkwa/1/). You might have more success if you put the logo as a transparent texture to a flat grid geometry (`THREE.PlaneGeometry`) with a high subdivision count.

Comment: I'm now looking into that. Thank you :)